# How to link .gitignore to local project when generated through project creation on github?

Tags: git

I need to commit an Android project to git.

I've created a new project on Github and selected the selections for adding .gitignore with all the Android files to be ignored.

Now I need to commit the Android project for the first time into that repo:

Step 1. go to the project location and do `git add .`
Step 2. `git remote add origin https://github.com/projectlocation`
Step 3. `git commit - m "My First Commit"`
Step 4. `git push -u origin master`

Following these steps question is how do I link the .gitignore file so those files don't get pushed? Or does it automatically not push those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a new Android project, then a `.gitignore` file would have been generated. Just make sure that the `.gitignore` that is in your local project is the same as the one that is on your GitHub repo.

If the project is old, and there is no `.gitignore` file, you can create a new one in the root directory of the project and then you can do it two ways:

- Manually copy the content from `.gitignore` that is on GitHub and put it into local `.gitignore` (not recommended)
- (Recommended) Set your remote with

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

and then do

```
git pull
```

which will automatically import the `.gitignore`, `LICENSE` or `README.md` file that is there on GitHub, to your local project.

Then you can commit and push the normal way, and the unwanted files will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks my bad, you're right it was just hidden on mac. I have the file, just need top copy the content so its the same as the project in git. Then commit push the normal way. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Although @Gourav's answer is good, I'd like to give a more thourough explanation:

If the `.gitignore` is created before an ignored file is committed for the first time, it is done automatically (that should be the case for your new project).

If you first do a `git add someFileThatShouldBeIgnored.xxx` (and presumably also a `git commit`), your file will be added to Git even if it appears in the `.gitignore` as the file was versionned before it was told not to.

To remove a committed file that should not have been:

1. Add that file to `.gitignore`.
2. Use `git rm --cached someFileThatShouldBeIgnored.xxx` to un-version it (`--cached` keeps the file in your project, if ommitted, the file will be deleted from your local directory as well).
3. Commit those two changes together.